# Different game scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm having a weird error with a game I'm developing.. When button0 is clicked, then isInChallange is equal to false, when button1 is clicked, then isInChallange is equal to true. So in de GameViewController.swift file I'm using this code:

```
if isInChallange == false {

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        //skView.showsFPS = true
        //skView.showsNodeCount = true
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
    }
    if isInChallange == true {
        print("cmon")

        if let scene = challangeScene(fileNamed: "SecondGameScene") {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

When isInChallange == false, everything works fine, but if it's true I get this nasty error:

```
2015-10-07 15:12:57.977 Faster![3499:97107] Warning: Attempt to present <Faster_.GameViewController: 0x7f81fb56e1b0> on <Faster_.ViewController: 0x7f81fb648c00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any help is appreciated, really! Thanks!

Comment: Have you created a class called **challangeScene** and a .sks file named **SecondGameScene** in your project?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I created a .sks file, and now the at least when I print something inside if let scene, it is displayed, but I'm still getting the error